# Can a weaker currency be used to offset lower productivity of labour in an economy?

Tags: macroeconomics, currency

Can a weaker currency be used to offset supply-side (specifically low productivity of labour) problems of an economy to restore international competitiveness?

Comment: Assuming fixed exchange rate? Temporarily, it could, but at the cost of a jump in prices, due to the law of one price. If imports are used to produce goods that are exported, this might not prove so profitable.